NuxtJS SPA + Laravel API CORS Error even though SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS etc is set
I've installed laravel + breeze and NuxtJS
The request in my nuxt app is as follows:
await useFetch('http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie', {
credentials: 'include',
});

const token = useCookie('XSRF-TOKEN')

await useFetch('http://localhost:8000/login', {
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'post',
    body: data.value,
    watch: false,
    headers: {
      'X-XSRF-TOKEN': token.value as string
    }
  });

Here is the contents of my Laravel .env file
APP_URL=http://localhost:8000
FRONTEND_URL=http://localhost:3000
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost

When making the request I get this error
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8000/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
login.vue:15 
        
        
GET http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_FAILED

The network tab looks like this

The cookie seems to be stored correctly (Inside application->storage->cookies) so I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

Don't you need a http://localhost:3000/* for Laravel's CORS rules somewhere?

@kissu isn't that covered by this line in my config/cors.php file?
'allowed_origins' => [env('FRONTEND_URL', 'http://localhost:3000')],

I am not sure if it includes all the paths of the frontend. Most examples I saw had a wildcard.
